# Why doesn't JAXB allow annotations on getters that all pull from the same member variable?

Tags: java, spring-mvc, jaxb, jax-ws, cxf

Why does example A work, while example B throws a "JAXB annotation is placed on a method that is not a JAXB property" exception?

I'm using JAX-WS with Spring MVC.

**Example A**

```
package com.casanosa2.permissions;

import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlAccessType;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlAccessorType;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlElement;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlType;

@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.PROPERTY)
@XmlType(name = "FooXMLMapper")
public class FooXMLMapper implements IFoo {

 @XmlElement
 private final boolean propA;

 @XmlElement
 private final boolean propB;

 public FooMapper(IFoo foo) {
  propA = foo.getPropA()
  propB = foo.getPropB()
 }

 public FooMapper() {
  propA = false;
  propB = false;
 }

 @Override
 public boolean getPropA() {
  return propA;
 }

 @Override
 public boolean getPropB() {
  return propB;
 }
}
```

**Example B**

```
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.PROPERTY)
@XmlType(name = "FooXMLMapper")
public class FooXMLMapper {

 private final IFoo foo;

 public FooMapper() {
  foo = new IFoo() {

   @Override
   public boolean getPropA() {
    return false;
   }

   @Override
   public boolean getPropB() {
    return false;
   }

  };
 }

 public FooXMLMapper(IFoo foo) {
  this.foo = foo;
 }

 @XmlElement
 public boolean getPropA() {
  return foo.getPropA();
 }

 @XmlElement
 public boolean getPropB() {
  return foo.getPropB();
 }
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I believe the accessors are ignored if it's looking directly at the instance variables and in your example B there are no actual instance variables of the right name. You have to tell it explicitly to use @XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.NONE) on the class and @XmlElement and @XmlAttribute on the get/set methods. At least, that's what I ended up doing with my JAXB mapping.

Comment: Bernard is using property as the access type so only the get/set method should be checked.

Comment: You were right, adding XmlAccessType.NONE fixed it.  Now I don't have to have silly member variables duplicating data that I already have. :)

Comment: XmlAccessType.NONE will work, but it is not correct.  NONE means only map what is explicitly annotated.  If you use FIELD or PROPERTY then you can take advantage of defaulting.  I still believe your issue involved specifying PROPERTY access but annotating fields.

Comment: I'm glad it worked, though Blaise is right that what you had should have worked with the accessors and I was mistaken. I ended up using XmlAccessType.NONE because I had lots of properties (accessors) I didn't want showing up in the XML and some I did. It was easier for me to say NONE and then explicitly specify the ones I wanted.

Comment: Blaise I'm not sure I follow.  Example B is the one that failed and there I annotated the getters. I did not annotate the member variable since I did not want that in the XML as it is only an interface and would not be understood anyway.

Comment: I understand Example B is the one that failed, but Example A was the one that looked funny :).  If you want to exclude one property @XmlTransient is normally used, this way you can accept the defaults on the other property.  XmlAccessType.NONE will also work but it means that you have to annotate every field you want to include, this is more useful when you only want to include a small percentage of fields.  Either way I'm happy you are up and running.

Comment: @bdoughan in my case, i'm calling an external api which is extremely unreadable, and i've found it very useful to just give up on defaults and explicitly annotate every element while keeping variable names readable and also, my sanity.

Answer (score 2):

I believe for it to be a proper JAXB property, you would need setters for them as well as getters.   (you would likely need a default constructor as well).

Comment: You do not need both get and set methods.  A property with only a getter will be considered write-only.  A property with only a setter will be considered read-only.

Comment: @Blaise: Other way round, surely? (JAXB basically only knows about annotated methods…)

Comment: Only getter = write property to XML only as there is no setter to read from XML.  Only setter = read property from XML only as there is no getter to get data to write to XML.

Comment: I have default constructors, it doesn't add the type to the web service WSDL if you don't have one.

Answer (score 2):

I haven't tried your code yet, but it's example A that looks wrong, not B.  In example A you have specified the property accessors (get/set methods) but you have annotated the class fields instead (instance variables).